# How does a lot of metal "come alive"?

Tags: computers

Very good to everyone.
I'm new in this forum.

I have a somewhat existential doubt.

How does the transfer of information to an electronic device work? For example, I can hardly see the idea of ​​a lot.
metal, cables, etc. (like a pendrive for example) I managed to save the information of an (for example) mp3.
It is as if that metal comes to life.

I know that the quick explanation is through designed circuits, digital, etc. But this does not satisfy me as an explanation, I would like to go to why. I have a hard time assimilating the idea that
a set of metals achieves "acquire life" to store all kinds of information, etc.

I ask this to understand how from nowhere (lots of sand in the past etc.) a computer could be built.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You might want to read something like Charles Petzold's *Code*. There's no way we can give you a satisfying answer in the space available here.

Comment: It's all about the transistor. Making a weak signal stronger is what it's all about. That + Boolean Algebra and you have a computer that has "come alive".

Comment: There's a lot of wisdom on the web if you can learn

Comment: We store charges in most cases. Then we use very small transistors, whose conductivity varies adequately when exposed to a small charge. Google "sense amplifiers" for some explanations. And also read about cross-coupled inverters, which store ONE BIT.

Comment: Biology is pretty similar when you think about it except with a bunch of chemical reactions. Even a car engine is fairly similar with it just being a hunk of metal.

Comment: No-one can understand the metal to application range in one go, so we break it up into layers. We have a layer of physics, that makes transistors out of atoms. Then logic, makes gates and memory cells from transistors. Then an addressable memeory from cells. Then the secret sauce is humans saying 'this pattern of bits means 'A''. Now if you remember, we've already said earlier in history that 'this pattern of letters' is a word, and patterns of words represent 'ideas', and move people to great things. So to store manuals, or music, or images in 'metal' involves many layers of abstractions.

Comment: Actually the questioner has seen the future after a big disaster. Humans are again building a new culture. Our current science and technology have shrinked to fairy tales of the past glory. The priests have still some mysterious relics which seem to have a life when they get some sunshine, but no prayers nor spellings seem to give a contact to that life, no matter how hard or nicely one tries to sing the still undecoded diagrams and texts in the rare remaining manuals.

Comment: Same way a piece of paper comes alive when a wyriter or artist makes black marks on it.

Answer (score 2):

If we just talk about the transfer and storage of (digital) data in very simple and broad terms it comes down to one basic concept:

The data which is represented by a series of 0's and 1's can instead be represented by a series of high and low voltages. That series of voltages can be applied to a wire/cable and sent somewhere else.

Then the voltages need to be stored in some way. How exactly they are stored can be pretty complicated, but the original and most simple method was to just punch holes in a bit of paper. That is still basically how it is stored, but the paper is replaced with flash memory or such.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the phonograph record or the compact disc, here inert objects store information in their fine detail.

with electronic storage it is also though fine detail that the storage is achived, but with electronic memory the fine detail is mutable by the appliction of electomotive force, so that charged can be moved into or out of the cells of the flash memory so that each bit of information can be rewritten after the final manufacture of the storage media.